# How to keep a hidden element visible after going to another page and returning?

Tags: local-storage, backend, visibility, display

I'm making a birthday card website for my dad. There are five buttons you can click to reveal different popups. Once all the buttons have been clicked, a hidden link to a photo gallery appears.  In the gallery, there is the option to close the gallery and return to the card, but once you return to the card, it returns to the original state, hiding the link.

I'm thinking of storing a value in localStorage that checks whether all the buttons are pressed, but would localStorage keep that value once I go to a separate gallery page?

Or since I want to manage a state on a page after I close it, do I need servers? etc? I've only been working in the front end, so this is out of my ballhouse.